# Apache (Homebrew) on macOS Monterey not reachable from network

Tags: macos, homebrew, apache

I've installed Apache using Homebrew on a Mac Studio (M1) running Monterey and it works fine when working locally. But when I'm working on a website from a separate Ubuntu laptop, I often cannot access the website on the Mac; the request is pending.

But when I now connect to the mac by SFTP and navigate around, the web request suddenly succeeds as if I had to "wake up" the Mac.

Maybe there's a setting to tell macOS that it should wake up on TCP requests on port 80 as it does on SSH requests?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.
Other services like sshd and vnc do work, but not Apache.

UPDATE: I kicked (i.e. rebooted) my Mac and it worked again.